# Scale long line of text down

Tags: context

I'm using Context to generate a book. Most of my chapter titles are short and fit in the space allotted to them. However a few are slightly too long, I'd like to scale those down to fit.

Trying something like `\scale[factor=fit]{Title}` works except it also scales the shorter titles up making them look too big. Is there a way to tell Context to only scale if the text is too long?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  i'm not a context user, and i know the syntax is very different from either plain tex or latex, but there must be a way of measuring the length of an output string.  save the string in a box, measure the width, and scale only if it's too long.  context may have a more "compact" way of expressing this, but that's the basic mechanism.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Conceptually that makes sense, how might that actually look in plain Tex?

Comment: in plain tex: `\setbox0\hbox{<string-to-be-tested>} \ifdim\wd0 > <max-width-allowed> <do-scaling> \fi`.  don't know offhand how scaling would be done in plain tex, but that's not the problem you're looking at. make sure that the "correct" font is used in the <string-to-be-tested>; using a 10pt font to measure, when the string is usually set in 12pt, will get the wrong result. (mind, i'm not really in favor of scaling; if the use of such a string is for a running head, it's much preferable to "abbreviate", or use more than one line for the main title, but your circumstances may preclude this.)

Comment: Awesome, I think I can make that work! I would prefer not to do the scaling at all, but I think in this case it's going to be the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to handle text which is longer than a certain width when you don’t want to start a new line.

The first method is to scale the text down when it exceeds a certain length, you can set the limit for your text with the `maxwidth` key for the `\scale` command.

```
\setuplayout[width=8cm]

\starttext

\scale[maxwidth=\textwidth]{Short title.}

\scale[maxwidth=\textwidth]{A very very very very very very very very very very very long title.}

\stoptext
```

[image: Use of the \scale command to limit the text width.]

The second method is cut the text after a certain length with the `\limitatetext` command and display a text or symbol which indicates the rest of the text.

```
\setuplayout[width=8cm]

\starttext

\limitatetext{Short title.}{\textwidth}{\unknown}

\limitatetext{A very very very very very very very very very very very long title.}{\textwidth}{\unknown}

\stoptext
```

[image: Use of the \limitatetext command to limit the text width.]

Answer (score 4):

**Note**: Metafox's answer is better. Use that instead.

Here is a basic implementation of Barbara's idea:

```
\define[1]\ScaleToTextwidth
    {\setbox\scratchbox\hbox{#1}%
     \ifdim\wd\scratchbox>\textwidth%
        \scale[width=\textwidth]{\unhbox\scratchbox}%
     \else
       \unhbox\scratchbox
    \fi}

\starttext
\ScaleToTextwidth{Ward}

\ScaleToTextwidth{\input ward\endgraf}

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

I scaled everything to `\textwdith`; if you wish, you can keep that configurable as well.

Comment: You don’t need the check for the width of the content when you use the `maxwidth` key: `\scale[maxwidth=\textwidth]{...}`.

Comment: @Metafox Interesting, in all my searching, I didn't run across that key...

Comment: @Metafox: can you post that as an answer.